Calcular la altura de un rectángulo en FPDF
En un documento PDF estoy dibujando un rectángulo con esquinas redondeadas y necesito que la altura que se da a ese rectángulo vaya de acuerdo a la cantidad de registros a imprimir.
Tengo el siguiente código PHP:
$inventario = Inventario::getInventario();
         
$alto = count($inventario) * 0.8;
         
$this->SetDrawColor(215, 216, 227);
$this->RoundedRect(0.8, 5.2, 20, $alto, 0.7, '1234', 'D');

$this->SetFillColor(149,140,142);
$this->SetDrawColor(149,140,142);
$this->SetFont('Calibri','B',12);
         
$this->Cell(.3,.8);
$this->Cell(3.3,.8,'C. Barras',1,0,'L',true);        
$this->Cell(6.7,.8,utf8_decode('Descripción'),1,0,'L',true);
$this->Cell(3,.8,'P. Compra',1,0,'C',true);
$this->Cell(3,.8,'P. Venta',1,0,'C',true);
$this->Cell(3,.8,'S. Actual',1,0,'C',true);
$this->Ln(.8);

if(is_array($inventario))
{
    $this->SetFont('Calibri','',12);
             
    foreach($inventario as $inv)
    {
        $this->Cell(.3,.8);
        $this->Cell(3.3,.8,$inv["codigo"],0,0,'L');
        $this->Cell(6.7,.8,utf8_decode($inv["descripcion"]),0,0,'L');
        $this->Cell(3,.8,'$'.number_format($inv["compra"], 2),0,0,'C');
        $this->Cell(3,.8,'$'.number_format($inv["venta"], 2),0,0,'C');
                   
        $stock = $inv["stock"] - floor($inv["stock"]);
                   
        $this->Cell(3,.8,$stock > 0 ? number_format($inv["stock"], 3) : $inv["stock"],0,0,'C');
        $this->Ln(.7);             
    }
}

Lo que yo pensé es multiplicar la altura de cada celda por el total de registros a imprimir, por ejemplo si cada celda tiene de altura 0.8 y son 18 registros a imprimir entonces la altura a asignar al rectángulo a dibujar sería de 14.4 pero resulta que esto que pensé no es del todo correcto por que deja espacio considerable despues del ultimo registro o el ultimo registro queda fuera del border inferior de ese rectángulo, ejemplo en las imagenes siguientes:


Como puedo solucionar este problema para que la altura del rectángulo a dibujar quede de acuerdo a la cantidad de registros a imprimir??
Estoy usando la librería FPDF con PHP.

Es complicado calcular la cantidad de espacios ocupados por la fuente y el interlineado, sobre todo si las fuentes no son monoespaciadas.
Sin embargo la propia librería FPDF trae métodos que devuelven dónde quedó el cursor luego de generar una celda, y es justo lo que necesitas: GetX() y GetY(). Para este caso se guardan en un array de coordenadas x, y: $fpXY
Entonces debes dibujar el rectángulo después de imprimir el contenido.
[*] En este caso hice pruebas con la versión v1.86 (25/06/2023), y los valores en milímetros (mm). Coloqué unos valores iniciales ($sx y $sy) que representa desde dónde se va a imprimir.
Por cierto, la fuente Calibri me daba error así que usé Arial.
[Nota] Como ya han impreso otras cosas en la cabecera del inventario, te tocará extraer el valor GetY() del final de esas cabeceras para que a partir de ahí se genere el vértice superior izquierdo del rectángulo.
<?php
// require_once 'fpdf.php'; // roundedrect.php ya hereda de fpdf.
require_once 'roundedrect.php'; // https://www.fpdf.org/?go=script&id=35

class PInvent extends PDF {
    private $sx;
    private $sy;
    
    function __construct($orie='P', $unit='mm', $size='A4', $sx=10, $sy=10) {
        FPDF::__construct($orie, $unit, $size);
        $this->sx = $sx;
        $this->sy = $sy;
        # ###
        $this->AddPage();
        $this->SetMargins($this->sx, $this->sy);
        $this->SetX($this->sx);
        $this->SetY($this->sy);
    }
    
    public function prtTable() {
        $inventario = Inventario::getInventario();
        
        $this->SetFillColor(149, 142, 142);
        $this->SetDrawColor(149, 142, 142);
        $this->SetFont('Arial', 'B', 12);
        
        $this->Cell(40, 10, 'C. Barras', 1, 0, 'L', true);
        $this->Cell(50, 10, utf8_decode('Descripción'), 1, 0, 'L', true);
        $this->Cell(25, 10, 'P. Compra', 1, 0, 'C', true);
        $this->Cell(25, 10, 'P. Venta', 1, 0, 'C', true);
        $this->Cell(25, 10, 'S. Actual', 1, 0, 'C', true);
        $fpXY = [$this->GetX(), $this->GetY()];
        $this->Ln();
        
        if(is_array($inventario)) {
            foreach($inventario as $inv) {
                $this->SetX($this->sx);
                $this->Cell(40, 10, $inv["codigo"], 0, 0, 'L');
                $this->Cell(50, 10, utf8_decode($inv["descripcion"]), 0, 0, 'L');
                $this->Cell(25, 10, '$'.number_format($inv["compra"], 2), 0, 0, 'C');
                $this->Cell(25, 10, '$'.number_format($inv["venta"], 2), 0, 0, 'C');
                $stock = $inv["stock"] - floor($inv["stock"]);
                $this->Cell(25, 10, $stock > 0 ? number_format($inv["stock"], 3) : $inv["stock"], 0, 0, 'C');
                $fpXY = [$this->GetX(), $this->GetY()];
                $this->Ln();
            }
        }
        
        // Dibujar el rectángulo
        $this->SetDrawColor(215, 216, 227);
        $this->RoundedRect($this->sx-5, $this->sy-5, $fpXY[0]-5, $fpXY[1]-15, 5, '1234', 'D');
    }
}

$pdf = new PInvent('P', 'mm', 'letter', 15, 35);
$pdf->prtTable();
$pdf->Output('F', 'output.pdf'); // <-- Obtener la salida en archivo local

La salida con 2 registros de prueba:

La salida con 6 registros de prueba:

